# Detecting Remote OS in php

Tags: php, http, http-headers

I am creating a site that will allow guests to submit their website and it will cache a copy of their page.

Is there a way to display the remote server's OS using a php script?

Comment: clarifying the question, sounds like you want the remote server's OS

Comment: What library are you planning to use to download the copy of the page? (Guzzle, Httpful, unirest, pecl_http?)

Answer (score 0):

Check the `Server` HTTP response header. WARNING: Many systems will turn this off as a security measure. Otherwise there isn't anything easy.

See these questions for more information/references:

- [How to detect web server type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097472/how-to-detect-web-server-type)
- [How to detect OS version of a web server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9164161/how-to-detect-os-version-of-a-web-server)

Comment: There are other methods but they are invasive, and even illegal in some cases.

Comment: I am using curl_exec to get the contents of the site. This task looks harder than I thought.  I understand that some methods are illegal but I will be using for the legal way